# Can't override system brightness in UWP app

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I tried to override system brightness from my UWP app. But When I tried to get BrightnessOverride instance, the code breaks at the below line.

```
var bo = BrightnessOverride.GetDefaultForSystem();
```

It throws a generic exception

> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL
>   has been returned from a call to a COM component.'"

I have check the '**System Management**' capability in manifest.

Note: I am running the app on my local machine.

Comment: On your local machine, go to Windows 10 Settings > Display.  Is there a brightness slider at the top?

Comment: @SeanO'Neil, Yes I have in my local system. But I need to control it from my UWP app through UWP APIs.

Comment: Ok just making sure you were testing on a system where the OS can actually control the brightness. Hopefully someone can help you out.